# Javascript Chart: How to hide the data

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm making a page using [chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org) (I'm also testing zingchart). This libraries use data in a format like:

```
series: [{
    name: 'Installation',
    data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175]
}, {
    name: 'Manufacturing',
    data: [24916, 24064, 29742, 29851, 32490, 30282, 38121, 40434]
}],
```

Is there any way to hide this data from the source code?

I'm seeing the source code of a lot of pages with similar charts, but I cannot find the data in the source code or in linked files. Maybe the data is obfuscated.

Answer (score 1):

Those pages receive data from the server-side scripts and so they are encapsulated within an array or object that is obtained from the response of the server. You are generating data on the client side I guess. That is why it is visible in source code.

Comment: Thanks! Any clue on where to begin looking information about how to receive data from server-side scripts? Actually, I have the data in a json file that is on the server. I'm using a shell script to update the json file every x minutes and I'm using js to fetch and process the data from the json file. The js code is in the html file.